# Read rights on list items

Tags: permissions

I have a problem on my Sharepoint 2013 site, users can't view items in list created by another user, unless they are in site collection admin group if they are in that group they can see all created items. 
The problem isn't in **Versioning Settings**, who should see draft items in this list. I set that on Any user who can read items. Also in list advanced setting in **Item-level Permissions** Read access:   Specify which items users are allowed to read. I set that on Read all items.
Also all members which can't see items created from another users are in Owners group with Full Control level permission

Please help!!

Comment: Click on any item -> shared with -> advanced -> Check Permissions. You can review the permission setting on that particular item. I suspect item-level permission is setup by some reason.

Comment: When I open shared with on any item  I see only Site collection admins and person who created this item, but i don't see advanced button

Comment: Seems we are on the right track. The "shared with" indicate item level permission is not "any user can read". Please refer [this article](http://aanuwizard.com/2012/08/setting-up-item-level-permission-for-a-list-item-or-document-in-sharepoint-2013/) for the step to check.

Comment: It was a bug or something on list, It didn't want to work, so I open a new custom list and it worked. Thanks everyone!